# Tinymce.js editor in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, google-chrome

For 3+ years I had a custom styles menu in my Wordpress editor that I added in functions.php which worked great.

Today, I went in to edit a new post, and not only doesn't my menu work, but I cannot switch to the text-only view in the post editor.

I get a console error in Chrome (Version 52.0.2715.0 canary (64-bit)) of

`tinymce.min.js?ver=4308-20160323:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined`

My menu shows but does not work, and the "text/visual" toggle does not respond either.

Both of the above things work in Safari 9.1 as always.  Any ideas?  Bug in Chrome?

Comment: did you update to WP 4.5? if so could be a conflict with the new jQuery version. one possibility anyway.

Comment: Yes, I did.  But shouldn't the tinymce get updated along with it?  I didn't add any custom js, just php.

Comment: yes but hmmm if you are adding custom tinymce controls in functions.php (?) then it's possible the jquery selectors the controls are using are not getting the target elements correctly anymore and therefore passing an undefined element to tinymce which makes it fail. still just a guess.

Comment: 4.5.1 is going to be released ( April 26 ) which fixes issues with Tiny MCE in Chrome. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/04/22/4-5-1-release-candidate/

Comment: That's great to know.

Comment: For others coming across this, upgrading from 4.5 to 4.5.1 fixed this issue for me.